# How do I create a dict/list of queries with scores then randomly select some to add up the scores?

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have some `.csv` data like this:

```
query, score1, score2, score3

kobe bryant,0,3,1,
ccny,1,1,2,
lego,3,1,0,
disney,4,0,0,
power rangers,2,0,2,
britney spears,2,0,2,
backstreet boys,2,1,1,
soccer,3,0,1,
justin beaver,2,0,2,
new york knicks,2,1,1
```

After adding up the scores I hope to get something like:

```
score1 = 10; score2 = 4; score3 18;
```

How do I go about splitting this up and adding them up?

Here's what i have so far:

```
import random

def getScores():
    # open files to read
    web = open("page.txt", "r");
    img = open("image.txt", "r");

    # scores for each search engine results
    gScore = 0;
    bScore = 0;
    yScore = 0;

    webDict = [];
    imgDict = [];

    # split by ','
    tmp = img.read().split(",");
for i in range(0, len(tmp)-4, 4):
        gScore = gScore + int(tmp[i+1]);
        bScore = bScore + int(tmp[i+2]);
        yScore = yScore + int(tmp[i+3]);

    print "gScore is: ", gScore, "\n";
    print "bScore is: ", bScore, "\n";
    print "yScore is: ", yScore, "\n";  

    tmp = web.read().split(",");
    for i in range(0, len(tmp)-4, 4):
        gScore = gScore + int(tmp[i+1]);
        bScore = bScore + int(tmp[i+2]);
        yScore = yScore + int(tmp[i+3]);

print "gScore is: ", gScore, "\n";
    print "bScore is: ", bScore, "\n";
    print "yScore is: ", yScore, "\n";  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    getScores();
```

This will add up all the scores, BUT I am having trouble creating a dict from the data.

What I mean is something like this:

```
bigList = [ 'query':{score1:int, score2:int, score3:int}, 'query2':{score1:int, score2:int, score3:int}... and so on];
```

Comment: @Marcin edited with code and more details

Comment: Good, now can you distil the task you don't know how to accomplish (doing something with a dictionary?) and leave out the rest? Nobody wants to read your homework, so asking a better question is a good way to get helpful answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've split it at the commas, it can easily be processed in a single line:

```
gScore, bScore, yScore =  
          [sum(map(int, scores)) for scores in (data[n::4] for n in range(1, 4))]
```

The `data[::4]` part takes every 4th item from the data, starting at the appropriate offset for each type of score. You then convert each type to integers and sum them up.

Answer (score 1):

I'd split the string by commas first:

```
stuff = 'kobe bryant,0,3,1,ccny,1,1,2,lego,3,1,0,disney,4,0,0,power rangers,2,0,2,britney spears,2,0,2,backstreet boys,2,1,1,soccer,3,0,1,justin beaver,2,0,2,new york knicks,2,1,1'
parts = stuff.split(',')
```

`len(parts)` is supposed to be a multiple of `4`, otherwise you can throw an exception:

```
if len(parts)%4:
   raise ValueError('bad csv')
```

Then do something like:

```
d = {'score1': 0, 'score2': 0, 'score3': 0}
for i in range(len(parts)/4):
     d['score1'] += int(parts[4*i+1])
     d['score2'] += int(parts[4*i+2])
     d['score3'] += int(parts[4*i+3])

print d
```

I get

```
{'score1': 21, 'score2': 7, 'score3': 12}
```

Comment: You don't need the loop: `sum(parts[1::4])` etc. Maybe even `dict(("score%d" % n, sum(parts[i + 1::4])) for i in (1, 2, 3))` (untested).

Comment: Thanks for reminding about that fancy extended slice notation. It comes in really handy sometimes.

Comment: @WolframH My answer shows how to do it with only implicit loops :)

Comment: @agf: Didn't see your answer when I typed my comment. Upvoted it :-)